# How to load one page at a time in CarouselPage

Tags: xamarin.forms

say, I have created a Grid at the very top (look like a Navigation Bar) contains a few buttons: btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4.

Problem: how to show one page at a time in CarouselPage base on btn click. Btn1 will show Page1 and so on. No swiping is allowed.

Below: I use < local:page >  to insert the page which created outside.

```
<CarouselPage 
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"    
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"       
x:class ="MyApp.MainPage"
xmlns: local ="clr-namespace:myApp"
>

<local:Page1></local:Page1>

<local:Page2></local:Page1>

<local:Page3></local:Page1>


</CarouselPage>
```

Comment: If no swiping allowed you don't need carousel. Use for example empty view as container and add/remove children (your views, not pages)